# How can I use Wikipedia opensearch API with Typeahead.js?

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead, wikipedia-api, twitter-typeahead

Can someone give me a code example of how I can use Wikipedia open search API with Twitter `Typeahead.js`? I know I should call it from ***remote*** option but I don't know how to retrieve the values.

#### For example:

This is the json response, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=opensearch&lang=en&search=hello

```
[ "hello",
  [ "Hello",
    "Hello Kitty",
    "Hello My Name Is...",
    "\"Hello, World!\" program",
    "Hello Venus",
    "Hello Good Morning",
    "Hello! Project",
    "Hello Hurricane",
    "Hello Kitty (Avril Lavigne song)",
    "HelloWallet"
  ],
  [ "Hello is a salutation or greeting in the English language. It is first attested in writing from 1833.",
    "Hello Kitty (Japanese: ハロー・キティ, Hepburn: Harō Kiti), (full name: Kitty White (キティ・ホワイト, Kiti Howaito)) is a fictional character produced by the Japanese company Sanrio, created by Yuko Shimizu and currently designed by Yuko Yamaguchi.",
    "Hello My Name Is... is the debut studio album by American singer-songwriter Bridgit Mendler released on October 22, 2012, through Hollywood Records.",
    "A \"Hello, World!\" program is a computer program that outputs \"Hello, World!\" on a display device, often standard output.",
    "Hello Venus (Hangul: 헬로비너스; often stylized as HELLOVENUS) is a South Korean girl group formed by Tricell Media, a joint venture between Pledis Entertainment and Fantagio, in 2012. It was announced in July 2014 that the two companies had ended their partnership, with the remaining members continuing under Fantagio.",
    "\"Hello Good Morning\" is a song by American rapper and producer Diddy and his band Dirty Money, from their debut album, Last Train to Paris.",
    "Hello! Project (ハロー!プロジェクト, Harō! Purojekuto) is a Japanese idol project, the umbrella name for a collective of female singers who are under contract with the Up-Front Group and whose recordings are produced by Tsunku.",
    "Hello Hurricane is the seventh studio album by American alternative rock band Switchfoot. On February 13, 2011, the album won the award for Best Rock Gospel Album at the 53rd Grammy Awards.",
    "\"Hello Kitty\" is a song by Canadian singer-songwriter Avril Lavigne, taken from her self-titled fifth studio album, Avril Lavigne (2013).",
    "HelloWallet, wholly owned subsidiary of Morningstar, Inc., is a web and mobile application for employees, founded by former Brookings Institution scholar Matt Fellowes."
  ],
  [ "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_Kitty",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_My_Name_Is...",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_Venus",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_Good_Morning",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello!_Project",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_Hurricane",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_Kitty_(Avril_Lavigne_song)",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HelloWallet"
  ]
]
```

This is a `typeahead.js` with remote, that obviously doesn't work.

```
var wikiSuggestions = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=opensearch&lang=en&search=%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
  }
});

$('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'wiki',
  display: 'value',
  source: wikiSuggestions
});
```

How can I get it to work? I don't know how to retrive all the titles of the suggested pages, so of the array with the article titles.

Comment: What does the data look like? Do you know how to use ajax to call a remote api?

Comment: @whipdancer I just don't know how I can tell the script to retrieve all the values in the array of the titles. I know it's easy, but it's the first time I use typeahead.js, and there are not many examples online. On `jQueryUI autocomplete` I don't have problems.

Comment: dont use typeahead.js, it has almost 300 open issues and is not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform it using javascript.

```
function openSearchConverter(osResults){
  console.log(osResults);
  var results = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < osResults[1].length;i++){
    results.push({
      name: osResults[1][i],
      desc: osResults[2][i],
      url: osResults[3][i],
    });
  }
  return results;
}
```

The other code is simular execpt for `filter: openSearchConverter` in:

```
var wikiSuggestions = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=opensearch&lang=en&search=%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY',
    filter: openSearchConverter
  }
});
```

You refer to the object using `displayKey: 'name'` in:

```
$('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'wiki',
  displayKey: 'name',
  source: wikiSuggestions
});
```